# Diablo 3 Spirit Stone

Tags: diablo-iii

I am trying to finish the achievements in Diablo 3 and one of them I can't complete since I have to buy the Spirit Stone.

The achievement is: 
    Shut Up and Take My Money!

I can't find it anywhere in 1.0.8. Any one got it? any one knows where to buy it?

Thanks

Comment: @SimonL yes I am sorry, I didnt specify which one I was trying to accomplish

Comment: This goes into some good detail about what NPCs people had success with. The important thing to note is that the wares are random so it is mostly an RNG thing. I haven't tried any of it so take it as it is. http://d3db.com/achievement/i/shut-up-and-take-my-money